# What is a Choice Principle, really?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

*This question is quite soft, and I apologize in advance if it borderline off-topic.*

When working in theories between ZF and ZFC the term "choice principle" is heard quite often. For example:

$\quad$ **The Axiom of Countable Choice**: Every countable family of non-empty sets has a choice function.

We can say, if so, that a choice principle is an assertion about choosing. On the other hand, the above axiom is equivalent [1] to the following assertion:

$\quad$ Every $\sigma$-compact space is Lindelöf.

However this statement does not talk about choosing anything. The first alternative is to define a choice principle as something equivalent to a choice-referring statement, but what about the ordering principle?

$\quad$ **Ordering Principle**: Every set can be linearly ordered.

Commonly thought of as a choice principle, the order principle is not really equivalent to any choice principle directly. It does however prove that every family of non-empty and finite sets has a choice function.

Maybe we can define a choice principle as something which *proves* some sort of a choice statement. Alas this too can be troublesome, consider the Small Violations of Choice principle:

$\quad$ **SVC**: There exists $S$ such that for every $x$ there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x\leq\mathcal P(\alpha)\times S$.

It is consistent with the existence of an amorphous set AND a countable set of pairs without a choice function that SVC holds, so it doesn't even imply the axiom of choice for pairs.

So we may wish to define a choice principle as follows:

> Let $\varphi$ be a sentence in the language of set theory, $\varphi$ is a choice principle if ZF does not prove $\varphi$, but ZFC does.

This definition catches the wanted properties of a choice principle, it is simply an assertion in between the two theories. However in [a recent comment on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176425/stronger-than-zf-weaker-than-zfc#comment405768_176436) Carl Mummert suggested that this definition is also problematic, since the assertion: $$\lnot\rm AC\rightarrow\text{Con}(ZF)$$
Is not provable from ZF, but vacuously true in ZFC.

This leads to the question:

> **Question:** What would be a good definition for *Choice Principle* (in ZF), which encapsulates the notion of a statement "between" ZF and ZFC, but still avoids vacuous statements as above?

---

**Bibliography:**

1. Brunner, N. [**σ-kompakte Räume. (German. English summary) [σ-compact spaces]**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=667922)
   *Manuscripta Math.* **38** (1982), no. 3, 375–379.

Comment: I think the Ordering Principle is a coherent choice principle in the same spirit as Rado's Selection Principle. We are asked to choose an orientation for each edge in a complete graph in such a way that the transitive law holds. Coherent choice principles are relatively common. For example, Dependent Choice can be seen as a coherent form of Countable Choice.

Comment: Francois, that is an interesting assertion. If we consider an equivalent formulation of the Selection Principle, *KWP($1$)* (Every set can be embedded into the power set of an ordinal); how would you describe the general principle, namely *KWP($n$)* "Every set can be embedded into the $n$-th power set iteration of some ordinal"?

Comment: I don't remember saying anything about that. In any case, KWP sounds like a "mapping control principle" like SVC and others. I think that's a different taxonomy.

Comment: François, I don't remember saying anything about you saying anything about that before. I merely pointed out that I am interested in what you had to say when we replace the selection principle by an equivalent assertion, and what you have to say on the generalizations of that equivalent statement. 

Comment: Recall that SVC is similar in nature to WISC/AMC(new version), in that it proves there is a small category of anafunctors between two small categories. WISC is manifestly a choice principle, in that it states that every epi can be split by passing to one of a set of suitable covers. I don't know if SVC can be put into such a form, and a priori it is not actually equivalent to WISC, so take this as a sort of analogy.

Comment: I extend this discussion in my blog post: http://boolesrings.org/asafk/2013/choice-principles-what-are-they/

Answer (score 16):

Here is a way to think about Carl's example, which seems to undercut your interpretation of it as vacuous, and allows us still to think of it as choice principle. Namely, the statement $\neg\text{AC}\to\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ is equivalently expressed as:
$$\neg\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})\to\text{AC},$$
which says that if a certain number-theoretic principle holds, then we have full choice. I regard this as a choice principle---perhaps one would call it a *conditional* choice principle---because it asserts the full power of AC, provided a certain requirement is met. This would seem to be a choice principle even in the intensional sense mentioned by Andrej. It asserts that we may make our choices, provided that we first verify that the combinatorial assertion $\neg\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ holds. This particular example is a weak choice principle, because ZF plus this axiom, if consistent, is strictly between ZF and ZFC.

There is of course nothing special about $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ here. If $\Phi$ is any statement provable in ZFC, then over ZF it is equivalent to $\neg\text{AC}\to\Phi$, and hence also to $\neg\Phi\to\text{AC}$. Such a form of the principle can be viewed as a conditional assertion of the axiom of choice, even in the intensional sense, since it asserts the full power of AC, providing a certain requirement is met. In this sense, any statement $\Phi$ provable in ZFC and not in ZF, including any of the usual weak choice principles, may be viewed in this way also as a conditional choice principle.

This seems to allow us to retain your proposal that a statement $\varphi$ is a choice principle if it is provable in ZFC, but not in ZF.

Comment: I am quite fascinated by this rather syntactical vs. semantical approach to the idea.

Comment: Hi Joel, you might be interested to know that I picked up the topic of this thread in a recent blog post, http://boolesrings.org/asafk/2013/choice-principles-what-are-they/. 

Answer (score 13):

When we speak of a "choice principle" we are discussing the meaning of a statement, not its truth value, i.e., the usual statement AC got its name because of what it means and not because of its truth status. However, logical equivalence preserves only truth values but not meanings. Thus the statements "all unicorns have two horns" and "1 + 1 = 2" are both true, hence equivalent, but they have different meanings. Likewise, the axiom of choice and the well-ordering principle have different meanings, even though they are equivalent. If you wonder about AC being equivalent to a well-ordering principle, you should also wonder about many other equivalences in mathematics that relate statements with different meanings.

As for your question "what is a choice principle, really?" I would say that choice principles are a certain kind of reversal of quantifiers. The axiom of choice can be stated as
$$(\forall x \in A . \exists y \in B . \phi(x,y)) \implies \exists f \in B^A . \forall x \in A . \phi(x, f(x))$$
where $\phi$ is a relation between the sets $A$ and $B$. This form of the axiom of choice does not require any set theory, just a bit of simple type theory and first-order logic (if you read schematically in $\phi$).

**Exercise:** convince yourself that the above statement is equivalent to AC. Hint: given a family of sets $C_i$ indexed by $i \in I$ let $A = I$, $B = \bigcup_{i \in I} C_i$ and $\phi(i, x) \iff x \in C_i$. Conversely, given $A$, $B$ and $\phi$, let $I = A$ and $C_i = \lbrace y \in B \mid \phi(i,y)\rbrace$.

A category theorist might say that choice is about splitting epis.
Indeed, given a family $C_i$ indexed by $i \in I$, consider the map $e : \coprod_{i \in I} C_i \to I$ defined by $e (i,x) = i$. Then $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of non-empty sets if, and only if, $e$ is surjective (epi), and it has a choice map if, and only if, $e$ has a right inverse (is split).  Conversely, to split an epi $e : A \to B$ is the same as to give a choice function for the family of sets $C_i = \lbrace x \in A \mid e(x) = i\rbrace$ indexed by $i \in B$.

**Supplement:** in answer to Trevor, here is how one might phrase dependent choice categorically. I do not know whether there is a slicker formulation. Given $1 \to A$ and $e, p: B \to A$ with $e$ epi, there is $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ such that there is a factorization $h: \mathbb{N} \to B$ of the span $f, f \circ \mathrm{succ} : \mathbb{N} \to A$ through the span $e, p: B \to A$. This looks nicer as a commutative diagram, how do I draw one of those? Anyhow, I do not see a particular advantage over the usual formulation. Perhaps someone can improve this.

Comment: This matches my opinion, which is that the notion "choice principle" is intensional rather than extensional. Thus Tychonoff's theorem is not a choice principle, in my opinion, although it's equivalent to AC over ZF. There are infinitely many principles between ZF and ZFC of the form $(\lnot AC) \lor \phi$, where $\phi$ is a sentence of PA involving consistency statements which is true in every well founded model of ZF. Can all these be "choice principles"? By analogy: the existence of an inaccessible cardinal implies Con(ZFC) but I would not say that Con(ZFC) is itself a large cardinal axiom. 

Comment: Carl, perhaps post an answer with more details? I also think that some people do regard $\text{Con}\rm ZFC$ as a large cardinal axiom in *some* sense.

Comment: Can DC be similarly phrased in category-theoretic terms?

Comment: @Trevor: sure, it is not as nice as AC though. It also takes a couple of paragraphs to prove, so perhaps this should be a separate MO question. Or I can add it to my answer, as you wish.

Comment: The collection schema $\forall x\in a\,\exists y\,\phi(x,y)\to\exists w\,\forall x\in a\,\exists y\in w\,\phi(x,y)$, provable in ZF, is a prime example of a quantifier reversal principle. Do you also consider it to be a choice principle?

Comment: I would not say so, a characteristic of choice is that it goes from $\forall x \in A \exists y \in B$ to $\exists f \in B^A \forall x \in A$, i.e., we pay attention to what happens to the domains of quantification and somewhere functions $A \to B$ have to come into play. Your collection schema looks to me like an axiom, and replacement should be its consequence. And by the way, there other interesting things to be said about quantifier reversal. When the domains stay the same, it is about topology (often). 

Comment: Hi Andrej, I wrote a blog post on this topic, http://boolesrings.org/asafk/2013/choice-principles-what-are-they/ in case you are interested in a further discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am glad you are peeking outside Cantor's cage and seeing there is life after ZF. Still, I maintain that logical equivalence does not preserve meaning, only truth values. I can take your insistence that anything equivalent to a choice principle is a choice principle to an absurd conclusion: the statement "1 + 1 = 2" says that there are infinitely many prime numbers. After all, it is equivalent to the statement. So indeed you have to look at the form of the statement, not its truth value or what it might imply, to discover whether it is a choice principle.

Comment: I think that you and I are both zealots, or the mathematician versions of zealots, of opposite camps. I don't think I am locked in Cantor's "cage", and despite being a strong agnostic in almost every aspect possible - I still have some requirement from a philosophy of mathematics, and that includes LEM, at least to the extent that finiteness and countability are absolute (every set is countable or uncountable and not both; similarly for finiteness). But I am uncomfortable with the lack of LEM. 

Comment: In either case, I hope you will take my call for suggestions more seriously than pointing out that $1+1=2$ is equivalent to "There are infinitely many primes", and therefore the idea of requiring a choice principle to have a definition stable under logical equivalence (say over ZF, or whatever) is preposterous. I am interested in finding a reasonable way of formulating what is a choice principle, and I do hope to have a definition which will satisfy a broad range of mathematicians, rather than "classical" set theorists, or just type theorists, or whatever. Best wishes, 

Comment: I am not a zealot, at least not one of the kind you imagine me to be. Whether something is a choice principle is independent of whether it is phrased in this or that theory. So in particular, LEM is irrelevant here. To me a choice principle is about the fact that total relations contain functions, I don't see what more you want. (Oh, by the way, in the effective topos there is a set which is neither finite nor infinite.)

Comment: Regarding writing dependent choice categorially:  Take the universal property of the set of natural numbers ([diagram](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object#CCC)) and reinterpret it so that the non-vertical arrows are entire relations instead of functions.  (Only the map $A \to A$ is actually weakened; the others are still functions for other reasons.)  The (repeated) vertical arrow, which the property claims must exist, is still a function, but we no longer require it to be unique (which would be false).  The resulting statement is DC.