# What is a chess piece mathematically?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, chess

Historically, the current "standard" set of chess pieces wasn't the only existing alternative or even the standard one. For instance, the famous [Al-Suli's Diamond Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr_bin_Yahya_al-Suli#Al-Suli%27s_Diamond) (which remained open for more than one millennium before getting solved by Grandmaster [Yuri Averbakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Averbakh)) was formulated in an ancient Persian variant of chess, called [Shatranj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatranj), using a [fairy chess piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece), called [Wazir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazir_(chess)) (Persian: counsellor), rather than the conventional queen.

There is a long-standing discussion amongst chess players concerning the best possible configuration of chess pieces which makes the game more exciting and complicated. Also, one might be interested in knowing whether, in a fixed position on the infinitary chessboard, the [game value](http://jdh.hamkins.org/game-values-in-infinite-chess/) could be changed into an arbitrary ordinal merely by replacing the pieces with new (possibly unconventional) ones rather than changing their positions.

In order to address such questions one first needs to have a reasonable mathematical definition of the notion of a "chess piece" in hand.

Maybe a promising approach inspired by [Rook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph), [Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_graph), and [King's graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_graph) is to simply consider a chess piece a graph which satisfies certain properties. Though, due to the different nature of all "reasonable" chess pieces, it seems a little bit hard to find principles which unify all of them into one single "neat" definition. For example, some pieces can move only in one direction, some others can jump out of the barriers, some have a/an finite/infinite range, some can only move among positions of a certain color, etc.

Here the following question arises:

> **Question.** What are examples of mathematical papers (or unpublished notes) which present an abstract mathematical definition of a chess piece? Is such a definition unique or there are several variants?
>
> **Update 1.** In view of Todd and Terry's comments ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287917/what-is-a-chess-piece-mathematically#comment712555_287917) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287917/what-is-a-chess-piece-mathematically#comment712616_287917)), it seems a more generalized question could be of some interest. The problem simply is to formulate an abstract mathematical definition of a "game piece" in general. Are there any references addressing such a problem?
>
> **Update 2.** As a continuation of this line of thought, Joel has asked the following question as well: *[When is a game tree the game tree of a board game?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288123/when-is-a-game-tree-the-game-tree-of-a-board-game)*

Comment: The chess rules are already abstract and define the structure of chess rigorously.

Comment: Since chess can be played "in the head", there is no need for chess pieces at all.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Of course for *every variant of chess*, we have rigorous well-defined rules but as a game with a long history, "chess" has many variants with different rules and pieces. For example, there are chess games played on a three-dimensional chessboard! (The theory of infinite three-dimensional chess has been studied in some of Joel Hamkins' works. See page 443 of this slides for more information: http://jdh.hamkins.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Infinite-Chess-VCU-2014.pdf ). I don't see how and why one can consider one of them the standard version and the rest just "non-chess".

Comment: These comments don't really address the question.

Comment: The terminology "chess piece" is confusing and probably should be replaced. Clearly you don't mean physical pieces, and I don't think you mean the specific game of chess. (Also, among chess players, "piece" often means a non-pawn chessman.) My guess is that "abstract game piece", using chess as an example, comes closer to your intended meaning.

Comment: I interpret the question essentially as asking for a definition of what it means to be a chess variant. For example, checkers or draughts is not ordinarily viewed as a chess variant, but Fischer chess, bughouse and horde chess are. My opinion is that the category of chess variants does not have sharp boundaries, and any proposed definition will admit counterexamples. So I don't think there will be a fully satisfactory account.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Well, my question is actually not about the way one can define a "game piece" in general. Though, I relied on the "common sense" for what is called a chess game. However, I assume an exact definition of a "chess piece" (which works for all standard and fairy chess pieces) can't exist without a clear definition of a "chess game" including all variants of this game. Not to mention that I personally see a chess piece (chessman in your words) a graph with certain properties. But I have problems identifying the abstract properties that such a graph should satisfy.

Comment: If Joel's interpretation is correct, then the question seems to have little hope of being solved (as he said). After all, even in ordinary chess there are such bizarre rules (like castling, capturing *en passant*, even pawn promotion) -- how to draw a strict line between that type of game and checkers? Capturing in checkers could be seen as just a variant of capturing rules for pawns, and king-ing in checkers just a variant of pawn promotion.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins My question is somehow related to what you have mentioned. Anyway, I think it is still interesting to consider non-standard chess pieces which highly affect the game value and the winning strategies. For example, consider the piece corresponding to the complete graph in the chessboard with the jumping ability. It is a super powerful piece (superman) which ends the game in the first move because there is nowhere to hide from its fierce threat for the opponent's king! Modifications of superman covering "almost all" (but not all)    places on the board are also interesting.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Hmmm... Seems (disappointingly) true! :-( Anyway, I did my best to "MathOverflowize" the ambiguous yet intrinsically natural question.

Comment: "There is a long-standing discussion amongst chess players concerning the best possible configuration of chess pieces which makes the game more exciting and complicated."
I am not so convinced chess players care about this. Even those that like to play and advance chess960 are doing it for the purpose of making chess more varied, but are not necessarily preferring one configuration over another.

Comment: If one draws an analogy between chess and fluid dynamics, then the chess pieces are the possible values of Lagrangian coordinates,
 while the 64 squares of the chessboard are the possible values of Eulerian coordinates.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field

Comment: @TerryTao What an amazing analogy, Terry! Actually, I didn't get it at the first glance but I gave it some thought and now I feel I can understand what you mean. It would be great if you explain the idea behind such an analogy in an answer or a more extended comment. What do these two (chess and fluid dynamics) have in common exactly?

Comment: @NikWeaver that’s why they’re comments, not answers

Comment: Maybe prepending 'the behaviour of' to most of the occurrences of 'a chess piece' in the question would make it a bit more readable.

Comment: in this connection, reading how chess (and its Japanese variant) were implemented on a neural network is instructive: https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01815 (today on arXiv)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker (+1) Interesting article! Thanks for sharing, Carlo! Here is more information about [Shogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi) (Japanese chess) for those who might be interested.

Comment: I second @Joel David Hamkins' diagnosis, but want to point out that this isn't always a devastating problem for mathematical research. The notion 'large cardinal axiom', for example, has no rigorous mathematical definition, but we tend to know one when we see one.

Comment: @NeilBarton (+1) Indeed, I do agree with you. By the way, there is a MathOverflow question addressing the same "lack of proper definition" problem for large cardinal axioms: **[What is the definition of a large cardinal axiom?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155558/what-is-the-definition-of-a-large-cardinal-axiom)**

Comment: IIRC, Mikhail Botnivik wrote a book on this back in the late 60's/early 70's (be aware, this was when CS was still part of Mathematics, so it is oriented toward the mathematical formulation of a computer program/process).  I think I still have it somewhere in my library, so I'll see if I can find it for reference.

Comment: Ah, I found it.  It's called "*Computers, chess and long-range planning*" M.M.Botvinnik, Heidelberg Science Library, 1970.  But now that I look at it, it doesn't seem like it would be that helpful.  It's pretty primitive from a CS standpoint and it doesn't really talk about mathematical representation of the pieces, so much as the mathematical representation of the *process* of chess itself.

Answer (score 133):

In terms of mathematical analysis and combinatorial game theory,
the essence of any game is captured by its game tree, the tree
whose nodes represent the current game state, and to make a move in
the game is to move from a node in this tree to a child node.
Terminal nodes are labeled as a win for one player or the other, or
a draw (and in the case of infinite games, the winner is determined
by consulting the set of winning plays, which in a sense defines
the game).

In chess, the current game state is not merely a description of
what is on the board, for one must also know whose turn it is and
also a little about the history of the play, in order to determine
whether castling or en passant is allowed or to determine draws by
repetition or the 50-move rule.

Once one has the game-tree perspective, the concept of chess pieces
tends to fall away, and one might look upon the concept of a chess
piece as epi-phenomenal to the actual game, a convenient way to describe the game tree: strategic
considerations concern at bottom only the game tree, not pieces.

In the case of chess, for example, the computer chess programs are
definitely analyzing and searching the game tree.

You ask for references, and any text in combinatorial game theory
will discuss the game tree and prove what I call the fundamental
theorem of finite games.

**[Fundamental theorem of finite games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_theorem_(game_theory)).** (Zermelo, 1913) In any finite
game, one of the players has a winning strategy or both players
have drawing strategies.

(Zermelo's actual result was something a little different than this; see the comments below and the interesting paper, [Schwalbe and Walker, Zermelo and the early history of game theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/FS23j.03/zermelo.pdf).)

This theorem is generalized by the [Gale-Stewart theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem#Background) (1953), which
shows also that every open game is determined, and this is
generalized to [Borel determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem) and more, and one then enters a
realm of sophisticated results in set theory.

Let me mention an example showing how two games can look very
different in terms of how they are played, yet at bottom be
essentially the same game, with isomorphic game trees.

Consider the game **15**, in which players take turns to select
distinct numbers from the numbers 1, 2, ..., 9. Once one player
takes a number, it is no longer available to the other player.
Whichever player can make 15 as the sum of three distinct numbers
is the winner.

Please give the game a try!

After a while, the game might begin to be familiar, for we can
realize that it is exactly the same game as tic-tac-toe, as can be
seen via the following magic square.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
      8 & 1 & 6 \\
      3 & 5 & 7 \\
      4 & 9 & 2 \\
    \end{array}$$

At the MoMath museum in New York, they have this game set up with a
two-sided display. On one side, for the parents, you see only the
numbers in a row. On the other side, for the kids, you see the
tic-tac-toe arrangement. How amazed the parents are to be beaten
soundly by their kids — all the kids are geniuses!

My point with this is that game of 15 and the game of tic-tac-toe are essentially identical as games, yet in tic-tac-toe there is directly no concept of number or selecting a number, and in 15 there is directly no concept of a corner square or center square. The nature of the number 5 in 15 is game-theoretically similar to the nature of the center square in tic-tac-toe, and this is revealed by the fact that the game trees are isomorphic. Chess pieces are like that.

Comment: (+1) A very good answer as usual! Thanks, Joel! Particularly, I enjoyed reading the last part about the MoMath museum.

Comment: I agree about the primacy of the game tree, and I'd add that the notion of "piece" may be, at least in part, a psychological one: Pieces provide a way to summarize the structure of the game tree in a way that we can understand. It would be interesting to have a game tree with two nontrivially different such summaries --- two seriously different notions of piece. (By "nontrivially", I want to exclude things like the tic-tac-toe example, where the numbers are just a relabeling of the squares.)

Comment: Yes, I agree: pieces are how we describe the game tree. And yes, I would find it interesting to have more examples of isomorphic game trees described by totally different manners of play.

Comment: I suppose there are many examples in combinatorial game theory, where various games are seen to be Nim in disguise.

Comment: I think the statement of Zermelo's theorem in the current form is slightly misleading; the result is not about finite games in the modern sense (games with finite game trees), but games with finitely many positions (that may occur infinitely often along a play).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Actually, I think of the result as applying to any game all of whose plays end in finitely many moves. These are the clopen games, and there can be infinitely many positions and the game tree can be infinite, as long as it is well-founded (=clopen).  So for me, finite game means a game all of whose plays are finite, and Zermelo's proof works in this case.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Zermelo does allow for infinite plays, but these plays are repetitions of finitely many positions. If a player has a winning strategy, they can force a win in at most as many rounds as there are positions, but "draws" need not terminate and such games need not be determined. There is a discussion of the original paper together with an English translation [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/FS23j.03/zermelo.pdf).

Comment: You want me to credit clopen determinacy to someone else? Zermelo's proof idea establishes the stronger result, even if it is true that he didn't consider the most general case. I would find it wrong to state the fundamental theorem in a weakened way, just because an early account didn't state it in what we now can see is a better way.

Comment: In your comment, you wrote about games "all of whose plays end in finitely many moves", but Zermelo looked at games that may plainly never end. I guess the difference is that the literature on determination of games looks at games in which every play is a winning play for some player.

Comment: I think the literature on clopen determinacy also considers games with draws, since that case is easily handled. To my way of thinking, I want to discuss what I call the fundamental theorem of finite games (by which I mean clopen determinacy), and I credit this to Zermelo because he had all the ideas necessary to prove it, whether or not he actually formulated his result that way. Historical work is valuable, but not the same as mathematics. I wouldn't state the fundamental theorem differently, just because Zermelo did, and I wouldn't credit it to someone else. What would you have me change?

Comment: I guess you are saying that Zermelo proved certain instances of open determinacy, if the game tree is produced from a game having finitely many game states. I suppose another way to say this is that the lower cones in the game tree realize only finitely many isomorphism types. This is less than open determinacy (Gale-Stewart), but also simultaneously more and less than clopen determinacy, since not all clopen games are like that, and not all games like that are clopen.

Comment: I added a remark and a link to that excellent paper. Thank you, @MichaelGreinecker!

Comment: I'm trying to think how one might go about finding an equivalent game to chess that gives you the same advantage that tic-tac-toe does to "15" but I can't think where I would even begin!

Comment: Great answer!  I've pondered, on occasion, whether partizan takeaway games such as chess can be reduced to Nim ;)  It also seem that traditional combinatorial games tend to be win/lose/draw, normal play or miserie, where newer combinatorial games like [M] introduce the concept of [strength of victory](http://www.fundamentalcombinatronics.com/rules-of-m/), which adds nuance to the terminal nodes.

Comment: I actually really like that example by the end and think it might serve as a good analogy and illustration to non-mathematicians what mathematics is all about: The game '15' seems difficult at first glance and keeping all possible moves and combinations in mind appears challenging. But once the superficial coating is stripped away and the 'true structure' of the game is revealed, it becomes manageable and intuitive. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to miss the point of the question.  The question is asking for a definition for a certain subset of games, and saying "it's just a tree" is too broad.  There are mathematical questions we can ask about chess variants, that don't make sense for general games.  For example, what subsets of pieces guarantee that I can checkmate a lone king?  Also see any of the "related" questions.  It seems you mention 50 move rule and castling to make the point that it's hopeless to make any definition besides "it's a tree", but in mathematical questions we usually just ignore those rules first.

Comment: (Not to say it isn't an interesting answer, and I may be interpreting the question as the one I want.)

Comment: I've seen this explanation before - but I think this is the first time I've actually grasped it! Thanks!

Comment: Tic-tac-toe is also identical to "do you want to let the other player win?" asked repeatedly to each player.  If a game doesn't have a winning play for either player (if perfect play leads to a draw), then the game is also equivalent to tic-tac-toe in that sense.  If we had a theory that didn't treat pieces as just another state element we might get a more interesting theory of pieces, if not games.

Comment: Perhaps the remarks about the special role of the "$5$/middle square" is most apt to the question itself. If I may indulge in a perhaps pointless speculation, it would be very interesting if one were able to examine the tic-tac-toe game tree, within it identify a sub-structure that corresponds to the "$5$/middle square", and somehow abstract or generalize that substructure to other games.

Comment: @Yakk The game tree of tic-tac-toe is not isomorphic to your game of "would you like your opponent to win?", since every play of tic-tac-toe ends in at most nine moves, but your game has infinite plays. And even if you limit your game to nine moves, then it isn't the same, since in tic-tac-toe, the game tree is branching with nine possible first moves and eight possible second moves and so on, and those plays are not homogeneous, since the game tree below some of them is not isomorphic.

Comment: @TimCarson I mostly agree with your comment. My answer was mainly intended to point out that all strategic considerations in a game have, fundamentally, to do with the game tree rather than with other aspects of the game. Meanwhile, I would find it interesting for someone to undertake a very high-level mathematical analysis of the following form: for which game trees can we identify a moving-piece form of the game?  ...ct'd..

Comment: Of course, for every game tree, we can imagine moving a piece on the game tree itself, used as a board, but what we want of course is a much smaller board and small number of pieces and rules, such that the game played with those pieces and rules give rise to the same game tree. In other words, which game trees are trees that arise from such a form of game? These are the games for which Zermelo's original analysis kicks in, concerning the number of game states. I would expect that the branching of the tree would be related to the number of pieces or the number of their possible moves.

Comment: I asked a question pursuing this line of thought at https://mathoverflow.net/q/288123/1946.

Comment: Is the Gale Stewart theorem really a generalization of Zermelo's theorem? In the definition of a G-S game on Wikipedia, moves are always chosen from the same set $A$, but in chess the set of available moves changes each turn.

Comment: @JackM One can easily handle that by saying that one loses immediately upon making an illegal move. So one really only needs an upper bound on the space of moves.  The Gale Stewart game conception is extremely general.  If one understands the fundamental theorem as clopen determinacy, then the Gale Stewart theorem generalizes this to open determinacy: in any game with the property that all wins for one player are known to be a win in finitely many moves (so the payoff set for that player is an open set in the product topology), there is a strategy for one of the players.

Comment: Your Tic-Tac-Toe result reminded my of a recent paper in behavioral Game Theory, which builds on that sometimes an isomorphic version of a game (choice rule, e.g. auction) is "easier understood" by the players: https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20160425

Comment: A nigh-sublime answer. In fact: It inspired me to visit the MoMath museum here in NYC for the first time two days ago. The only weakness in the tic-tac-toe analogy is that's not a game with a conceit of pieces moving such as chess, etc. I can at least imagine the idea of pieces that "take up space" (only move to another space by emptying current space) as some kind of meaningful constraint on a graph.

Answer (score 13):

Approaching this from the perspective of a computer programmer rather than a mathematician, my instinct is to try to isolate those properties of a chess piece that are unique to that piece, separating them from rules that apply to all pieces. For example, there's a general rule that you can't do anything that would leave your king in check, and a general rule that you can't move to (or over) a square occupied by one of your own pieces. Of course, we can conceive of pieces that were not subject to these rules, so we have to decide how much we want to generalize. Similarly, when you're dealing with the "aberrations" of castling, en-passent capture, and promotion, you have to decide whether and to what extent you want to create some model which treats these as special cases of something more general.

A chess piece is characterized primarily by the moves that are possible from a given square, which in turn can be characterized as the set of squares that would be reachable in the absence of obstacles, less the squares that are obstructed. The reachable squares are a function of the piece and the starting square, while the obstructed squares are a function of the state of the board (independent of which piece you are moving). You can generalize the concept of a "move" to a "transition in the state of the board" that includes other pieces moving (castling) or disappearing (captures), or pieces being transformed into other pieces (promotion). And you can generalize "the state of the board" to include not just the current positions of pieces, but also the history of the game, or a "distilled history" that contains only as much information as is needed to determine legality of moves (whether the King has castled, whether pawns are subject to en-passent capture).

In summary, the way to model a chess piece mathematically depends on how much you want to generalize from the rules of chess as they are, to the rules of all conceivable chess-like games. As always, the right amount of generality rather depends on what you want to do with the model.

Comment: "[There's] a general rule that you can't move to (or over) a square occupied by one of your own pieces." Except, of course, that a knight can move over a square occupied by one of your own (or your opponent's) pieces.

Comment: Well, if you define the rule in terms of lines between the centres of squares, the knight doesn't move over the centre of another square so you don't have to treat is as an exception.

Comment: Then castling is an exception, as you move the rook over the center of the square occupied by the king.

Answer (score 8):

The easy part is to say, "a pawn is one instance of type-pawn chess pieces". Hereafter I'll assume "a chess piece" is a piece type rather than an instance, which moves us onto the hard part.

The first temptation is to say it's a graph showing which $A$-to-$B$ moves are possible; for example, you might think, "oh, the rook graph has edges between those vertices denoting squares connected by a rank or file". But in practice whether the piece can move a certain way depends on other details, such as what piece instances (including their colours) are in the way and the game's history, which has implications for castling, en passant, whether the pawn can move two squares etc.

So a second stab at it is to say a piece is a function from past-and-present-state descriptions of the game to such legal-move graphs. For example, if there were a hypothetical piece that can go from $A$ to $B$ regardless of history and both piece colours' current placements, so long as $A,\,B$ are in the right relation, this function would be constant, always returning the same graph. But all the pieces you'll ever consider are non-constant functions.

If we now consider capture and promotion, however, we realise that the move to $B$ also lets a piece do something when it gets there; and if we consider castling, we realise the move also lets the King and Rook do certain things to each other. So an even better attempt at defining pieces, and hopefully the last one we need, is a function from past-and-present-state descriptions to the graph of legal changes in the game state. (Of course, states are so numerous this would be a graph with a huge number of indices.) Actually, I'll reword that once more: it's a directed graph of all legal history-to-history transitions. Each directed edge leads to a state in which the player's elapsed turn count increases by $1$.

Comment: So each piece is a subgraph of the graph of all possible state-to-state transitions. I.e., the subgraph composed of all the transitions where the piece moves?

Comment: @Bill That sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

A chess board represents an abstract space and a chess piece is a member of a set of finite elements where to each element is assigned a rule on how to change its coordinates in the abstract space.

These rules also depend on the positions of other pieces. For example, a rule for a bishop is that it cannot proceed past another piece in its way. But no such rule exists for a knight.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to represent a chess piece mathematically is to abstract away things like starting position or colour and only focus on what it can do. Thus it can be represented it as a triple (M, R, E) like this:

M is the set of vectors, representing all possible moves that the piece can take on an infinitely large board with no other pieces (or restrictions) on it.

R is the set of logical formulae, which given the history of the moves, the current position of the piece and a move m from M tells you if m can be done given the current state of the board.

E is a function from M, the piece's current position and the current board state to a new board state. This will tell you what (other) effects the move will have. For example, taking a piece or moving your rook if you are castling.

Using these 3 you can represent any chess piece and also compose them together to find out all possible moves that can be taken in a given board state. You could also represent other board game's pieces in a similar way, but you might also need to generalise one of the components depending on the rules of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Rereading the questions, I would simply answer that with the basic rule of chess one can consider the pieces as instances (or initializations on a game board) take from mobility classes that directly decsribe all the different mobility rules or a complete description of the board, possibly including a useful coordinate system to simplify the notation to write the different classes of mobility.  Is there a paper that does that, I do not know of any.  Should that be a reason not to share the above paragraph, i do not think so.

One can consider the king graph, and its representation embedded in R2 (a finite subset of R2 of course.  The grid of small square being actually a grid of points, with the links following the king mobility class (figure any way to create the link set, without referring to king mobility class, this is just to avoid typing in math.which i can't.   Or if R2 is not to ones liking, just go crazy with finite description of all the grid points.

In anycase, one can construct in finite human time, such mathematical objects.  And what would the question want more that such set description.  The word class is just used above the math. here. It the question was about the piece in a particular game, i would say, an initial condition on a game of the set of legal target grid points i called mobility class of the name of the piece you want.   In exaustive forumlation you would have to list all the source grid points, and all the target grid points, on an empty board.

If the conceptual bug is about the empty board description, then I need to go to the full formalism of a game or even position. Take the cartesian product of all pieces having been initialized in standard initial position.

legal moves can be reduced from all possible moves in that big multidimensional set, so that there are no collisions, and all the ruleset non-legal things one may list.   Using R2, is just to make such descriptions more compact, and generic.  One may even use intersection of 8x8 subset in R2  of bigger boards (even infinite) to reduce the typing even more. instead of making all the rim cases.  without blasphemy i would suggest to picture a real chess board from above. as a 2D grid of points.  assign placement of pieces to those point.. and notice that the ambient R2 space does not distract from the mathematics.

An answer above made similar point about whether to interpret the question as about the piece as instance or as mobility definition on the board.  As to the game tree question, I also share it. It puzzles me, when considering where all the games are evolving.  A game tree seems to assume only on game description, not all the games.  I mean a unique representation of all the games. Transposition seem to be getting in the way.  I would consider unique positions and moves as positions transitions. Each game can be view as a sequence of decisions among all the legal moves on such position defined representation, however the whole game world might not be "bijective" to a game tree (2 nodes on such tree, could be the same position).

sorry for bad English.  I am in process of editing.

Comment: I can delete the last paragraph. as this is me asking question on top of initial third question.  upon uproar to have it deleted. I am also looking for ways, to open my answer for those with better english that might understand the main points I am trying to express.  and if someones can point to existing papers doing the same. please share.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that the big multidimension set of empty board with one piece on each defined by a mobility set of pairs of grid points to choose at each move, is meant to be superimposed on the same 2D board  in order to apply the legal chess rules for obtaining a legal position successors.  both position and moves are described exploded and then superimposed back..   collisions being not legal for example.. go big then reduce. nothing really magical about it.

Comment: more erratum..  edit the above is dangerous for more details pouring..  so 8x8 intersection a mobility set of pairs of conveniently morphed Z2 subset embedded on R2.
each piece on board can have its own mobility set applied to any of its placements on board.  using the possibly shiffted in parts or dilated in parts infinte Z2 to describe the mobility in compact form to delegate the problem to implementation of the 8x8 intersection to instance computations, is still math.  right?

Comment: the more i explain the more i have to explain..  since no paper out there found in the answers, why not accept, ideas as answer.   if i could open this as a wiki, perhaps, people with same ideas but clearer expression, and math. touch typing confort. could fix this.
what matters is that the symetries of the board are kept in the morphing of Z2 within R2.  but some translation properties have to be kept. so that one can intersect properly a full infinite discrete space compact mobility figure math statement with 8x8 (also in same morphism).

Comment: one more precision..  i give up after that. asking for some imagination on reader beyond that.  discussion welcome. not just opinions though.  not all translations with vectors in R2.  only those compatible with the king walk directions.   there are 4 signed directions. (or is that orientation, i said signed did i not).

Comment: Ok for the instance question. I think in the line of some other post in terms of relations.  What did i mean by initialization.  Well. Resorting to my background in dynamical systems, I would say that one needs the discrete time game time variable, and the discrete space board coordinate variable.  The piece instance, would be  that mobility class piece (set of pairs of points, the figure, intersect 8x8, all morphed) with source grid point at the placement at specified time. so a relation between the mobility set, a placement variable, and a time variable.  (or bigger convention).

Comment: In passing, I think that the reference in the question is a bit premature.  I think all the posts above are fair game, while waiting for that.  I think it is a device in the question, to point at the lack of careful mathematical address of game objects.  Too much fitting the existing theorem in the past of the entrants in the math. of game objects.  In math. we can always fudge the givens and the obtained to make something consistent.  The art of math. modeling, is to be able to approach the reality, while keeping math. language.

Comment: Silly me, i forgot to add a set of indices..  for each pieces of same mobility class... 
but if listing them, maybe that is not needed. just carry the set of all of them. where notation begins versus mathematical object. it is a matter of choosing a representation, which is also a mathematical phrase.

Comment: relation not function.  (well function of indice only at t=0).  not a dynamical system after that (unless researching a bigger context) well more of a bundle of them, when not including player decisions.  including those, and only looking after the decisions, at the resulting position, each piece instanciated would still have only one point attached as mobility source, at any depth of decided path time steps..  i welcome others finding missing elements, for this elusive piece definition question to make it mathematical.

Comment: I think the problem of some formulation has been to want to state the mobility for all possible positions, without considering a bigger ambient space (i don't just mean ambient to the naked board, but to the initial positions and all its transitions.  That it can't be the result of super-imposing (or superposing) a higher dimensional space formulation.  The board itself as a graph can be described in a an ambient R2 description as I tried to explain.   But considering a position as the superposition of each solo piece on its own empty board, and applying core rules of legal chess.

Comment: Really. for references, if really asking for that, ask Deepmind. They had to do the same thing I described.  Maybe they skipped the math. for direct coded implementation. but I doubt it.

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27259/has-anyone-attempted-to-characterize-chess-mathematically