# Veblen function with uncountable ordinals & beyond

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, ordinal-numbers

**Disclaimer:** I am not a professional mathematician.

**Background:** I have been researching [large countable ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal) for awhile & I think the [Veblen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function) is particularly eloquent. My understanding is that [$\Gamma_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feferman%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtte_ordinal), the [small Veblen ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Veblen_ordinal) & the [large Veblen ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Veblen_ordinal) are all significantly smaller than the [first uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal) $\omega_1$. Having some extra time during quarantine, I had an idea to extend the Veblen function to the domain of uncountable ordinals & created the following notation. I would like to know how far this notation reaches & if anything [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726268/the-veblen-hierarchy-named-with-uncountable-ordinals-vs-ordinal-collapsing-funct) already exists.

**Note:** For the sake of brevity I have omitted numerous steps from the hand written derivation of this notation.

---

Consider $\phi_0'(\alpha)=\omega_\alpha$ such that:
$$\phi_0'(0)=\omega_0=\omega$$
$$\phi_0'(1)=\omega_1$$

Nesting these functions results in:
$$\phi_0'(\phi_0'(0))=\omega_\omega$$
$$\phi_0'(\phi_0'(\phi_0'(0)))=\omega_{\omega_\omega}$$

Next, consider the supremum of the previous nestings:
$$\phi_1'(0)=\sup\{\omega, \omega_\omega, \omega_{\omega_\omega},...\}$$

$\phi_1'(0)$ is then the first fixed point of $\phi_0'(\alpha)$ which correlates to $\phi_1(0)=\varepsilon_0$ being the first fixed point of $\phi_0(\alpha)=\omega^\alpha$ in the original Veblen function.

Continuing as in the original case, we eventually hit the limit of our single variable function. At this point ($\Gamma_0$ in the original), we turn to the multivariable function:
$$\phi_{1,0}'(0)=\phi'(1,0,0)=\sup\{\phi_1'(0),\phi_{\phi_1'(0)}'(0),\phi_{\phi_{\phi_1'(0)}'(0)}'(0),...\}$$

Again, like in the original case with the small Veblen ordinal, we eventually get stuck. At this point we move to the version of the Veblen function with a transfinite number of variables.

$$\phi'(1@\omega)=\sup\{\phi'(1,0),\phi'(1,0,0),\phi'(1,0,0,0)\}$$

Eventually this notation reaches as cap as well. In the orginal case, this is called the large Veblen ordinal & is the cap of the original Veblen function. In the expansion, we simply iterate our 'jump' operator:
$$\phi_0''(0)=\sup\{\phi'(1@0),\phi'(1@\omega),\phi'(1@\varepsilon_0),...\}$$

We can keep going by iterating the base function such that:

$$\Phi_0(0)=\sup\{\phi_{0}'(0), \phi_0''(0), \phi_0'''(0),...\}$$

Given the general form $\alpha_\gamma^\beta(\delta)$ we are essentially:

- maxing out $\delta \leadsto$ incrementing $\gamma$
- maxing out single variable $\gamma \leadsto$ multivariable $\gamma$
- maxing out multivariable $\gamma \leadsto$ incrementing $\beta$
- maxing out $\beta \leadsto$ incrementing $\alpha$

Repeating the process a couple more times results in:
$$\sup\{\Phi_0(0),\Phi_0'(0),\Phi_0''(0),...\}=\psi_0(0)$$
$$\sup\{\psi_0(0),\psi_0'(0),\psi_0''(0),...\}=\Psi_0(0)$$

Looping repeatedly reminded me of the original Veblen function process & so I created the following function:
$$\Xi(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)=\alpha_\gamma^\beta(\delta)$$

Such that:
$$\Xi(0,0,0,0)=\phi_0(0)=1$$
$$\Xi(0,0,0,1)=\phi_0(1)=\omega$$
$$\Xi(0,0,1,0)=\phi_1(0)=\varepsilon_0$$
$$\Xi(0,1,0,0)=\phi_0'(0)=\omega$$
$$\Xi(0,1,0,1)=\phi_0'(1)=\omega_1$$
$$\Xi(1,0,0,0)=\Phi_0(0)$$
$$\Xi(2,0,0,0)=\psi_0(0)$$
$$\Xi(3,0,0,0)=\Psi_0(0)$$

---

If you made it this far, thank you for taking the time. To reiterate, **how far does this notation reach** & **does anything like this already exist**?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Wojowu Is there any problems with this notation & how far does this reach?

Comment: I'm afraid MathOverflow is not the place to ask about general thoughts on some idea of yours (see [this meta discussion](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1818/30186)), though if you have some specific questions it will be more on-topic. As to how far it reaches - this is hard to answer, because there aren't any common notations which reach cardinals this large, bar any variations of the one you have just presented. No notation of this kind can reach an inaccessible, nearly by definition. High level indication is that ZFC proves such notations have limits, but it can't prove inaccessibles exist.

Comment: @Wojowu Based on your feedback & [this meta question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1590/is-this-a-known-interesting-result-type-questions?rq=1) I have updated my question. [Aside: I'm a big fan of your Higher order set theory]

Comment: @meowzz I am not sure whether I correctly understood all the definition that you proposed. Nevertheless the idea of making the analogue of Veblen functions by starting from $x\longmapsto \aleph_x$ instead of $x\longmapsto \omega^x$ seems to be pretty straightforward. Although, I am not familiar with any particular works that studied this, I personally have considered an analogue of Veblen functions based on $x\longmapsto \beth_x$ when I was studying superintuitonistic propositional logics that require frames of large cardinality for Kripke completeness (this never got to a publication).

Comment: @meowzz Nevertheless, if I understood correctly what you are doing here, this cardinals definitely have been considered before. Namely, if you look at stronger ordinal notation systems based on collapsing functions, in the same time they provide a notation system for (relatively) large cardinals. In particular consider the notation system that is used in analysis of $\Delta^1_2\text{-}\mathsf{CA}_0+\mathsf{BI}$  and $\mathsf{KPi}$ that collapses first inaccessible cardinal. In particular it has notations for your analogues of $\Gamma_0$, small Veblen ordinal, and large Veblen ordinal.

Comment: I haven't looked at the post in enough detail, but my impression upon a cursory look is that the following should be a safe upper limit. In OTM model add an extra tape or two basically serving as an "oracle" to calculate $\omega_i$ given $i$ number of $1$'s on the "advice tape" [shouldn't be too difficult to give equally powerful additional commands in other models]. I suppose this should be a safe upper-limit to cover the kind of cases mentioned in OP? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You might find 4.33 (p. 152) of Levy's [**Basic Set Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486420795) of interest. Let $A^{(0)}$ be the class of alephs, let $A^{(1)}$ be the class of ordinals $\gamma$ such that $\aleph_{\gamma}=\gamma,$ let $A^{(2)}$ be the class of ordinals $\gamma$ such that $\gamma$ is the $\gamma$-th ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\aleph_{\alpha}=\alpha,$ let $A^{(3)}$ be the class of ordinals $\gamma$ such that $\gamma$ is the $\gamma$-th ordinal in the enumeration of $A^{(2)},\ldots$ (process continues transfinitely so that $A^{(\beta)}$ is defined for all ordinals $\beta).$

Comment: Now take the diagonal intersection of the $A^{(\beta)}$'s to obtain the class of ordinals $\gamma$ such that $\gamma$ is the $\gamma$-th ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \in A^{(\beta)}$ for all $\beta < \alpha,$ and now repeat the process with the class of ordinals in the diagonal intersection, and continue for another diagonal intersection, and another and another into the transfinite, then look at ordinals $\gamma$ such that $\gamma$ doesn't show up as a least (nonzero?) ordinal in any of these classes until you've done $\gamma$ many diagonal intersections, $\ldots$

Comment: A useful google search is [Mahlo + cardinal + hyperinaccessible](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mahlo+cardinal+hyperinaccessible).

Comment: @FedorPakhomov I would be interested in reading what you wrote, if at all possible. I haven't seen much about ordinal collapsing functions with inaccessibles (I normally see them with uncountables) - but it seems interesting & I will look into it more. If you have any resources you would reccomend, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @SSequence I have looked at ITTMs a bit & have been wanting to look into OTMs. If you have any good reccomendations for resources I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro That portion of Levy's work does indeed look interesting! Also, I have made that Google search numerous times. Still having a bit of a hard time understanding even the smallest of the large cardinals..

Comment: *having a bit of a hard time understanding even the smallest of the large cardinals* --- I've pretty much given up on getting much of an understanding of how large they are (and they're a bit outside my main areas of expertise anyway), and I now mainly view them as larger than I could ever hope to reach by the kinds of vaguely explicit or the least bit constructive (in a very loose sense) modes of travel that I know about. It's as if I only know how to walk (proceed step-by-step) and I want to reach some of the distant quasars; another mode of travel is needed.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Well put! I would upvote your comment more times if I could.

Comment: @meowzz I am not sure what would be the best source for this. But you could check the paper "Ordinal notations based on a hierarchy of inaccessible cardinals" by Wolfram Pohlers.

Comment: What I believe is the slowest "mode of travel" faster than Veblin hierarchy methods was developed (I think) by Heinz Bachmann in early 1950s. The best introductory survey I know of (in English) is [*Normal functions and constructive ordinal notations*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272243) by Larry William Miller. See also, at least for the references, [*A survey on ordinal notations around the Bachmann-Howard ordinal*](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~buchholz/articles/jaegerfestschr_buchholz3.pdf) by Wilfried Buchholz (2016).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit long for a comment, but I'll make several points.

---

### These are not uncommon ordinals.

I've seen them used in Rathjen's ordinal collapsing function involving Mahlo cardinals, which he denotes $\Phi$. As the comments point out, they appear in various places.

---

### This is not at all how the multivariable Veblen function behaves (before the edit).

Your $\phi_{1,0}'(0)$ is simply $\phi_{\phi_1'(0)}'(0)$. It would be akin to saying that $\Gamma_0=\phi(\phi(1,0),0)$, which is not at all true.

To explain how the multivariable Veblen function works, I recommend seeing it as recursively closing over itself on lexicographically smaller arguments. In short, left-most arguments are more significant than right-most arguments. That is, we have things like $(1,0,0)>_L(\omega,0)>_L(3,0)>_L(2,\omega)>_L(1,0)$. From this, one can see that $\Gamma_0=\phi(1,0,0)$ is greater than $\phi(\alpha,\beta)$ for any $\alpha,\beta<\Gamma_0$. This can be shown to be equivalent to

$$\phi(1,0,0)=\sup\{\phi(1,0),\phi(\phi(1,0),0),\phi(\phi(\phi(1,0),0),0),\dots\}$$

but makes more sense when considering transfinitely many arguments.

---

### As far as I can tell, it's significantly smaller than the usual Veblen function modified with $\phi(\alpha)=\omega_\alpha$.

The Veblen function is already optimal, as far as this kind of recursion goes. Thus, the fact that your functions have significantly less arguments than the general Veblen function will make it much smaller. A quick look and I'd say only 5 or 6 arguments of the Veblen function would be needed to outperform your functions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I had a feeling I was not annotating $\phi_{1,0}'(0)$ correctly. I updated the equation, however am still unsure if this is the proper fundamental sequence. Wrt "the usual Veblen function modified w/ $\phi(\alpha)=\omega_\alpha$" - do you know of any literature that does this? I've only seen the idea mentioned a few times online & haven't actually seen anyone work through it. (Aside: did you create the $\omega_\star$ notation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83204/how-far-do-known-ordinal-notations-span/2252281#2252281) or does it come from somewhere?)

Comment: I would recommend steering away from fundamental sequences. These ordinals are not even countable, so even if they aren't regular, they may not have countable cofinality. Personally, I find it a lot simpler to work with the concept of closure: "what operations can apply to smaller ordinals that will not result in ordinals larger than $\phi_{1,0}'(0)$?" As I mentioned, I've seen it used in Rathjen's papers. I can try to pull this up later. Per the aside, it was made up on a whim.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Rathjen's notation system for $\mathsf{KPM}$ definitely covers this cardinals. But as I pointed out in my comment to this question, this cardinals would be already present if we collapse below the first inaccessible.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov That is likely true, but I don't remember off the top of my head if Rathjen had used $\Phi$ there.

Comment: I just want to note that I already understood what you put about the multivariable Veblen function. I just am not as sure about the notation of the version with transfinitely many variables. After looking a bit more I found something that put it as $\phi(1@\omega)$ which seems logical to me. I may modify this post soon to integrate that notation. My idea was that $\phi_0''(0)$ would be the supremum of the transfinitely many variables version. Also, while $\phi_\alpha'(\beta)$ might have similar strength (more, less or equal) to the normal function modified w/ $\omega_1$, what about $\Xi$?

Comment: @meowzz The Veblen function on transfinitely arguments works the same way as I have already described. With your fixes though, if I am understanding them correctly, $\phi_0''(0)$ would simply be $\phi(\omega@\omega)$. It is not clear what you mean to have after that, but everything is probably not past the Veblen function on $\omega+k$ arguments for maybe $k=2$ or $k=3$.

Comment: How would you annotate the large Veblen ordinal?

Comment: @meowzz With what? And I think we're kind of going a bit far off topic. If you want to, we could enter a chat room.

Comment: Chat would be great.

Comment: @meowzz We can chat in [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337) if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping an expert would answer this question so as to shed light on deeper or more profound points. As such, this is a basic answer covering some easy to understand points. This is based upon number of things I thought about years ago (it seems that some of those observations can be used in this question).

So let's start with your question "how far does this notation reach". I don't know what would be the answer to the question. It seems that to be able to answer though one would have to frame the question much more precisely (and I am not certain what that framing would be). Meanwhile the specific constructions you are posting (and far beyond that) are easily understood thinking in terms of generalized notion of being able to do complex calculations on ordinals.

For example, let's talk about something specific. In the beginning of your post you mention a way of starting with the function $x \mapsto \omega_x$ and how to arrive at an ordinal that is analogous to $\Gamma_0$. This analogy can be made precise using infinite programs that are sufficiently powerful. How so? Assume that a function $f:\mathrm{Ord} \rightarrow \mathrm{Ord}$ is "given" to the program. Exactly the **same** program that takes one to $\Gamma_0$ (given $f(x)=\omega^x$) will take one to "analogue of $\Gamma_0$" that you mention in your question. The only difference is that the function $f$ "given" to the program now is $f(x)=\omega_x$.

---

Now the same observations apply to bigger ordinals. I haven't studied the original Veblen paper so I am not 100% sure if the correspondences that I mention below are exact or not (so please correct if they aren't).

One way to think about SVO is in terms of a function $F:(\omega_1)^\omega \rightarrow \omega_1$. For example, writing $\omega_1=w$, we will have $\mathrm{SVO}=\mathrm{sup}\{\,F(w^i) \,\, | \,\, 1 \leq i<\omega\}$. This is analogous to thinking $\Gamma_0$ in terms of $F:(\omega_1)^2 \rightarrow \omega_1$. So, we will have $\Gamma_0$ as the first fixed point of the ordinal function $x \mapsto F(\omega_1+\omega_1 \cdot x)$.  Quite informally, I use the term "storage-functions" for these functions $F$. The $\omega_1$ isn't quite relevant in the sense that we just need an ordinal "big enough" ($\omega_{CK}$ would be sufficient in the above two cases). But anyway, that's besides the point. The point here is that when a function $x \rightarrow \omega^x$ alongside with a command of form $u:=\omega_1$ is given to us, then there is a specific infinite program which can compute the storage function (in input-output sense).

Is this relevant to your question? Yes. The same program that gives us SVO when given the function $x \mapsto \omega^x$ will take us to the "analogue of SVO" in the question (using the function $x \mapsto \omega_x$). But the issue of "storage function" seems to become trickier in this "analogue case".

**EDIT:** I am not suggesting to gloss over several important aspects such as equivalence of [different](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111995) definitions. If we are being fully detailed, I will admit the paragraphs above are quite insufficient. **END**

---

Finally, very briefly, towards the end you mention "extension" of transfinite variable. In the case of original hierarchy these kind of basic extensions would be handled by extending the domain of the "storage function" by a very modest amount. For example, from $F:(\omega_1)^{\omega_1}  \rightarrow \omega_1$ to $F:(\omega_1)^{\omega_1} \cdot \omega \rightarrow \omega_1$ etc. Similarly observations made earlier in this post about the "same" program taking us to the "analogue" of corresponding ordinal would apply (when given $x \mapsto \omega_x$ instead of $x \mapsto \omega^x$).

**EDIT2:** To OP (as a precaution): Please note that just writing $F:(\omega_1)^{\omega_1}  \rightarrow \omega_1$ (or anything of that sort) doesn't mean that the underlying function has been fully well-defined and neither I meant to imply that. In the given specific cases, precise definition can either be descriptive or based upon a (infinite) program which computes the function (given an extra command of form $u:=\omega_1$). Showing that the given def. satisfy certain desirable/required properties is bound to be more work. **END**

How time consuming it would be to write the detail of storage functions? For $(\omega_1)^2 \rightarrow \omega_1$ (starting with $x \mapsto \omega^x$) taking us to $\Gamma_0$ it should be fairly simple (though still a bit long to post all of it here). And then it gets lengthier, as it gets more complicated.

Comment: Nice approach! Do you have any good resources for infinite programs?

Comment: I do not know. A lot of them are quite technical. The usage of infinite programs here is quite basic. I am merely suggesting they can preserve the details of operations (in the same natural number) of using $x \mapsto \omega^x$  to go to $\Gamma_0$ and using $x \mapsto \omega_x$ to go to "analgoue of $\Gamma_0$" which you mention in the question.

Comment: The use of $F$ and $\omega_1$ as you describe is more or less equivalent to [Chris Bird's ordinal collapsing function](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Ordinal_collapsing_function#Bird.27s_.5C.28.5Ctheta.5C.29), and the analog of $\omega_1$ for the modified Veblen function would be an inaccessible cardinal or something of similar nature.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  "and the analog of $\omega_1$ for the modified Veblen function would be an inaccessible cardinal or something of similar nature" ...... Interesting observation. Yeah I wasn't sure (since I don't know anything about bigger cardinals etc.) about what would be the large-enough "container value" (analogous to $\omega_1$) when we are considering "storage function" in an extended manner such as in OP. That's why I left this point. Though I am reasonably certain that for the cases such as in OP we should be able to take some kind of supremum (continued)

Comment: of halt-values (of suitable programs) as an analogue of $\omega_1$ (for "container functions"). But I haven't really thought about it carefully enough. Regarding collapsing functions, I don't know anything about them (except that they are based on closure) ..... but anyway, that's besides the point. Anyway, I hope this comment of mine wasn't too confusing.

Comment: An inaccessible cardinal $I$ is regular and a fixed-point of $x\mapsto\omega_x$, which ensures that $F:I^\omega\to I$ is definable on all inputs (i.e. we never go beyond $I$).