# Is there a strict limit on choice principles in $\sf ZFC$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

> Is there a principle $\sf P$ that $\sf ZFC$ [or some suitable extension of it] proves to be a strict limit on choice principles?

By a choice principle I mean a sentence (or scheme) that is equivalent [over $\sf ZF$] to a selection principle. The latter is a sentence of the form:

$\forall x_1,..,\forall x_n \exists F  \forall y: \Omega \to F(x_1,..,x_n)(y) \in y$

Where $\Omega$ is a formula, that may use "$x_1,..,x_n,F,y$" among its free variables.

that is not provable in $\sf ZF$ alone.

By $\sf P$ being a strict limit on choice principles, it means that for every choice principle $\sf c$ we have $\sf ZFP \vdash c$, and $\sf ZFc \not \vdash P$; and such that there does not exist any principle $\sf H$ such that: $\sf ZFP \vdash H$, and $\sf ZFH \not \vdash P$, and for every choice principle $\sf c $ we have $\sf ZFH \vdash c$, and $\sf ZFc \not \vdash H$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no. Every theorem of ZFC is equivalent to a choice principle. I will prove this is true, but nevertheless also I will be first to agree that the manner in which this is true is trivial and ultimately unsatisfying. I take the real lesson here to be that the property of being a choice principle in this sense is not a useful notion.

**Theorem.** Every statement provable in ZFC is equivalent over ZF to a choice principle for a definable set family $\Omega$.

**Proof.** Suppose that $\psi$ is a sentence provable in ZFC. Define the family $\Omega$ so that it is the empty family, in the event that $\psi$ holds, and otherwise it is the family $V_\alpha-\{\emptyset\}$, where $\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that this family has no choice function. (Note that if $\psi$ fails, then AC must fail and so there will indeed be such an ordinal $\alpha$.)

I defined the family $\Omega$ so that ZF proves both that $\psi$ implies $\Omega=\emptyset$, and also that $\neg\psi$ implies that $\Omega=V_\alpha-\{\emptyset\}$, where $\alpha$ is least such that this has no choice function.

Now we argue in ZF. If $\psi$ holds, then the family given by $\Omega$ is empty, and so it vacuously has a choice function. And if $\psi$ does not hold, then AC fails and so indeed there is a first ordinal where the family of nonempty sets of rank below $\alpha$ has no choice function, and $\Omega$ is this family. So in this case, $\Omega$ does not have a choice function.

So the sentence $\psi$ is equivalent over ZF to the existence of a choice function for $\Omega$, as desired. $\Box$

The theorem is meant as a scheme over all $\psi$ that are provable in ZFC. So for each instance of the theorem, $\psi$ is a fixed sentence, and this sentence appears in the definition of the family $\Omega$.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what "if $\psi$ holds" and "if $\psi$ fails" mean. It's not about provability in ZF, but rather just a funky construction of $\Omega$ inside ZF, correct? Maybe there's a way to make this more explicit.

Comment: Yes, I am using $\psi$ in my definition of $\Omega$.

Comment: I tried to explain it a little better. Hope that helps...

Comment: And let there be no doubt that I view this family $\Omega$ in a purely instrumental manner---it enables me to prove the theorem and I make no claim about its naturality in any way beyond this.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I think there is a confusion here. It is obvious from the qualifications of $\sf P$ that it must not be a theorem of $\sf ZFC$ because $\sf AC$ is a choice principle. However, that answers to the positive whether every theorem of $\sf ZFC$ that is not a theorem of $\sf ZF$, is a choice principle? But, it doesn't answer this question. The theorem I asked for  whether $\sf ZFC$ or some suitable extension of $\sf ZFC$ proves it, is the statement ($\sf P$ is a ***strict*** limit on choice principles) and not $\sf P$ itself being the wanted theorem.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, by "principle" I mean a sentence or a schema of sentences in the language of $\sf ZFC$. A principle is not necessarily a theorem nor an axiom of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: I see. Because of the ZFC context, I had interpreted your question in the first-order language of set theory, for which AC is clearly the strongest choice principle, since it asserts that every set family has a choice function. But apparently you intend that the quantifier $\exists F$ is to be interpreted in some second-order manner? In this case, I am unsure exactly what the question is, since the second-order context is not specified. But I'll leave my answer here as a contribution on the nature of first-order choice principles.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, the quantifier $\exists F$ is first order. But, by $\sf P$ being a principle I don't mean a theorem of $\sf ZFC$, I just mean that $\sf P$ is a sentence or a scheme of sentences in the language of $\sf ZFC$. The question is whether there is a principle $\sf P$ such that ($\sf P$ is a strict limit on choice principles) is a theorem of $\sf ZFC$ [or some extension of it]. I don't know perhaps I'm missing something. By definition $\sf P$ must not be provable in $\sf ZFC$ because $\sf AC$ is a choice principle. For example $\sf P$ may be $\sf GCH$.

Comment: But in that case, why bother defining "selection principle" and "choice principle" and so forth, since AC is the strongest one and that would be the only one that matters. You are asking instead: Is there a minimal extension of ZFC? The answer is no, because the Lindenbaum algebra is dense.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I'm not sure of that. Perhaps a minimal extension with respect to choice. Anyhow, I didn't know of the Lindenbaum algebra relation to this subject. But, it appears this is the answer.

Comment: A possible candidate for Hamkins $\Omega$ is the formula: $$  (\psi \land y \neq y) \lor (\neg \psi \land \exists \alpha (\alpha= \min \delta: \neg \forall x \in V_\delta \exists H \forall w (w \in x \land w \neq \emptyset \to H(x)(w) \in w)) \land y  \in V_\alpha \land y \neq \emptyset)$$

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, let $\psi$ be $\sf AC$, then by your argument $\Omega$ is empty and so $\mathcal S^\Omega$ is actully $\top$. But this is not equivalent to $\sf AC$? See: https://mathoverflow.net/q/460872/95347, for the definition of equivalence of principles over $\sf ZF$. I must be missing something.

Comment: Suppose $\psi$ is AC. Argue in ZF as follows: if AC holds, then $\Omega$ is trivial and so there is a choice function for it. Conversely, if there is a choice function for $\Omega$, then we must be in the trivial case, and the only way this happens is when AC holds (by def of $\Omega$). QED  The error in your argument is that you say $S^\Omega$ is trivial, but ZF doesn't prove that; rather, it proves that this is true iff AC holds. The point is that the nature of $\Omega$ depends on the truth of $\psi$.

Comment: But actually you should say $S^\Omega$ is ⊥ not T, since when AC holds the family defined by $\Omega$ is supposed to be empty.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins. Yes, when $\Omega$ is empty,  $\mathcal S^\Omega$ would be $\top$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, by a "theorem of ZFC", do you mean those that are not theorems of ZF? Or, you mean literally any theorem of ZFC? If the latter, then it won't work, since the statement $\mathcal S^\Omega$ won't qualify for being a selection principle. So, the proper statement is that every theorem of ZFC that is not a theorem of ZF, is a choice principle, and vise-verse.