# Can the following definition of choice principle salvage the prior attempts?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, definitions

In prior postings [1](https://mathoverflow.net/q/460872/95347) , [2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/461016/95347), I've presented a definition of choice principle as what is equivalent to a selection principle. However, it was [proved](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461030/95347) that it is inadequate in the sense that it admits unwanted trivialities. This posting is an endeavor to salvage that method. Accordingly, the definition of choice principle would be modified to the following:

A choice principle is a sentence (or scheme) that is equivalent [over $\sf ZF$] to a selection principle. The latter is a sentence schema of the form:

if $\phi$ is a formula in which only the symbol "$z$" occurs free; then:

$\forall x_1,\dots,\forall x_n \exists F \forall y: \Omega \to F(x_1,\dots,x_n)(y) \in y \\ \exists x_1,\dots,\exists x_n \forall F: ( \forall y: \Omega \to F(x_1,\dots,x_n)(y) \in y) \to F \neq \{z \mid \phi\}$

Where $\Omega$ is a formula, that may use "$x_1,\dots,x_n,F,y$" among its free variables.

We denoted the above selection principle by $\mathcal S^\Omega$.

The idea is to avoid Hamkins argument of letting $\Omega$ be empty (thus $\mathcal S^\Omega$ being trivially true) when the principle at question [the one $\mathcal S^\Omega$ to be equivalent with] is true and otherwise $\mathcal S^\Omega$ being false. The additional condition of requiring the existence of a selection function $F$ over $\Omega$ that is not parameter free definable would block that argument. So any formula $\Omega$ satisfying Hamkins requirements won't qualify to define a selection principle! That is, $\mathcal S^\Omega$ is not a selection principle, because trivial selections are parameter free definable!

> Can this modification salvage this principle from the aforementioned argument? Or, the latter can be easily adjusted to overcome it?

To clarify, the definitions given here [the above one, or the one in P.S.] for 'choice principle' are based on "equivalence" notion, so they'd be rendered ineffective if they fall a pray to trivial equivalences like the one demonstrated in [3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461030/95347). To demonstrate, according to definitions given here a principle $\sf H$ is said to be a choice principle if it is consistent with $\sf ZF$, and not provable in $\sf ZF$, and if there is a formula $\Omega$ such that $\sf (ZFH \vdash \mathcal S^\Omega)$ and $\sf (ZF\mathcal S^\Omega \vdash H)$, this is the equivalence notion the definitions given here depend upon. The choice of $\Omega$ is very crucial here. Since if we allow $\Omega$ to be empty (as in [3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461030/95347)), then we'd be haunted by trivialities. The modification given above, which imposes a further restriction on $\Omega$, is aimed to avoid such trivial equivalences. However, it is not clear to me if an easy modification of [3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461030/95347) can vanquish it, and so render it ineffective. Hence, the question. So, for example the straightforward related question is whether it is still the case that every theorem of $\sf ZFC$ [and not of $\sf ZF$] is a choice principle? Especially if this can be proved trivially as in [3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461030/95347).

**P.S.** I've noticed that the above definition of selection principle would prove something that $\sf ZFC$ doesn't usually prove, that of existence of sets that are not parameter free definable. That said, its prudent to define $\mathcal S^\Omega$ as: $$\forall x_1,\dots,\forall x_n \exists F \forall y: \Omega \to F(x_1,\dots,x_n)(y) \in y$$

Provided that $(\mathcal S^\Omega)^+$ is consistent with $\sf ZF$, where $(\mathcal S^\Omega)^+$ is the schema:

if $\phi$ is a formula in which only the symbol "$k$" occurs free; then:
$\forall x_1,\dots,\forall x_n \exists F \forall y: \Omega \to F(x_1,\dots,x_n)(y) \in y \\ \exists x_1,\dots,\exists x_n \forall F: ( \forall y: \Omega \to F(x_1,\dots,x_n)(y) \in y) \to F \neq \{k \mid \phi\}$

Comment: Are you omitting some piece of notation? What does $F(x_1,...,x_n)(y)$ mean? A priori $F$ is just a variable in the language of ZF, is not it? For ZF variables $v$, $w$ I only understand what $v\in w$ means.

Comment: Yes it means F is a function, that is, a set of ordered pairs that meets the property of being a function, etc...

Comment: I was primarily asking about the rôle of $x_1$, ..., $x_n$. Am I right that $F(x_1,...,x_n)(y)=z$ means $\left\langle x_1,...,x_n,y,z\right\rangle\in F$ and it is given that for any $x_1$, ..., $x_n$, $y$ there is  a unique $z$ with $\left\langle x_1,...,x_n,y,z\right\rangle\in F$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, $F$ is a set of $n+1$ tuples, with the last entry of each tuple being itself  a unary function, so we have $\langle x_1,..,x_n,  \{ \langle  y, z \rangle .... \} \rangle \in F$, where $ \{ \langle  y, z \rangle, .. \} $ satisfy the qualification of being a function, i.e. we have one $z$ per a $y$ in its pairs. Think of it in terms of existence of a unary function $G$ that sends $y$'s to $z$'s, and $F$ is a set of tuples $\langle x_1,..,x_n, G \rangle$. So $F(x_1,..,x_n)$ will determine $G$, and $G(y)$ would determine $z$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, the $x_1,..,x_n$ are the *parameters* of selection, $y$ is the selected from population, and $z$ is the selected. See posting https://mathoverflow.net/q/460872/95347, for examples of the roles of those parameters. Those parameters are what enable you to have local choice sets per each set, instead of a global one.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, I forgot to mention that $F$ is not just a set of ($n+1$)-ary tuples, in addition it must meet the qualifications of being a function. So, per each $x_1,..,x_n$ there is a unique binary function $G$ such that $ \langle x_1,..,x_n ,G\rangle \in F$, the rest is clear.

Comment: So then $G$ is a set, depending on parameters, of pairs $\left\langle y,z\right\rangle$ satisfying the requirement of being a binary function for all values of parameters? Then is not $F$ a set of ($n+2$)-tuples $\left\langle x_1,...,x_n,y,z\right\rangle$ which becomes a function of $n+1$ variables $x_1,...,x_n,y$ with values $z$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე. No! $F$ is not a set of ($n+2$)-tuples. It is a set of ($n+1$)-tuples having their last projections being unary functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is exactly. Can you ask a precise question that doesn't refer to extended discussions/arguments from other posts?

Comment: I don't understand why you fuss with $\Omega$ etc. If $\exists F$ is meant to be a first-order quantifier (as you've expressed in the previous question), then $\Omega$ should simply define (from parameters) a set of nonempty sets. But then we don't care about the definability of it, since every set of nonempty sets is definable from a parameter, namely, the set itself. Why not just talk about set families of nonempty sets and whether they have choice functions? I seem to be missing something, but the whole set-up seems elaborately unnecessary.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I've edited. Regarding the fuss with $\Omega$ is because trivialities would spark if we unleash it as you  yourself have proved in an earlier posting. $\Omega$ is exactly meant to do what you are mentioning in your comment, we don't want it to succumb into unwanted situations.

Comment: So for each $x_1$, ..., $x_n$ you have a function of $y$, right? You then have a value for each $x_1$, ..., $x_n$, $y$, so you get a ($n+1$)-ary function, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, are you asking about how $F$ is defined here, or about how it can be defined? If the former then the answer is that $F$ is a set of $(n+1)$-ary tuples that meets the requirements of being a function and with the last projections of those tuples being sets of pairs that meet the requirements of being a function too. So, it is NOT a set of $(n+2)$-ary tuples. If you mean the latter then perhaps you can define $F$ alternatively in the way you are speaking about. So, what is the point from doing it alternatively?